# Implementing D3FC-Sample for data reduction

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, d3fc

I'm having issues with the correct implementation of a javascript library, specifically, d3fc-sample. It's a data reduction algorithm that I find useful for easing the burden of visualizing large data sets. Here is the repository:

https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc-sample

I followed the github instructions. Here is what I did:

1. downloaded node.js
2. node.js command prompt: cd local_host_directory
3. node.js command prompt: npm install d3fc-sample -g
4. tried to import into my d3 script

However, when I tried to run the page in my browser, this approach did not work. The developer tools gave me an error that said something to the effect of 'fc-sample is not defined'. So I asserted that the npm approach did not work. After which, I also tried using a tag as follows: `<script>src=file_path.largestTriangleThreeBucket.js</script>`. That didnt change anything either. I know very little about node.js, I suspect I did something wrong. Please drop a line if you have any tips. Library import solutions that don't involve node.js are also welcome.

You can see my index.html here: https://gist.github.com/diggetybo/f46ebec18dda16bf39f41b9282b5b593

Or the js script directly below:

```
<script>
    var width = 600,
      height = 400;

    var margins = {
      top: 10,
      left: 50,
      right: 50,
      bottom: 10,
      between: 50
    };

    var bottomGraphHeight = 50;
    var topGraphHeight = height - (margins.top + margins.bottom + margins.between + bottomGraphHeight);
    var graphWidths = width - margins.left - margins.right;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .style('font', '10px sans-serif');

    svg.append('defs')
      .append('clipPath')
      .attr('id', 'clip')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    var focus = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')');

    var context = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'context')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' +
        (margins.top + topGraphHeight + margins.between) + ')');

    var xScaleTop = d3.scale.linear().range([0, graphWidths]),
      xScaleBottom = d3.scale.linear().range([0, graphWidths]),
      yScaleTop = d3.scale.linear().range([topGraphHeight, 0]),
      yScaleBottom = d3.scale.linear().range([bottomGraphHeight, 0]);

    var xAxisTop = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScaleTop).orient('bottom'),
      xAxisBottom = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScaleBottom).orient('bottom');
    var yAxisTop = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScaleTop).orient('left');

    var lineTop = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d, i) {
        return xScaleTop(i);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScaleTop(d.y2);
      });

    var lineBottom = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d, i) {
        return xScaleBottom(i);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScaleBottom(d.y2);
      });

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(xScaleBottom)
      .on('brush', function brushed() {
        xScaleTop.domain(brush.empty() ? xScaleBottom.domain() : brush.extent());
        focus.select('.line').attr('d', lineTop);
        focus.select('.x.axis').call(xAxisTop);
      });


    var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/diggetybo/f46ebec18dda16bf39f41b9282b5b593/raw/70c279b9aef16f5348bc3185909c4b001414a611/wav_2.tsv";
    d3.tsv(url, function(error, rawData) {
      var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
        return {
          y2: +d.wav1
        }
      });

var sampler = fc_sample.largestTriangleThreeBucket();


sampler.x(function (d,i) { return i; })
    .y(function (d) { return y2; });

sampler.bucketSize(10);

var sampledData = sampler(data);



      xScaleTop.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d, i) {
        return i;
      }));
      yScaleTop.domain([-.02, .02]);
      xScaleBottom.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d, i) {
        return i;
      }));
      yScaleBottom.domain([-.02, .02]);

      var topXAxisNodes = focus.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 0 + ',' + (margins.top + topGraphHeight) + ')')
        .call(xAxisTop);
      styleAxisNodes(topXAxisNodes, 0);

      focus.append('path')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', lineTop);

      var topYAxisNodes = focus.append('g')
        .call(yAxisTop);
      styleAxisNodes(topYAxisNodes);

      context.append('path')
        .datum(sampledData)
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', lineBottom);

      var bottomXAxisNodes = context.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + bottomGraphHeight + ')')
        .call(xAxisBottom);
      styleAxisNodes(bottomXAxisNodes, 0);

      context.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x brush')
        .call(brush)
        .selectAll('rect')
        .attr('y', -6)
        .attr('height', bottomGraphHeight + 7);

      context.selectAll('.extent')
        .attr({
          stroke: '#000',
          'fill-opacity': 0.125,
          'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges'
        });

      styleLines(svg);
    });

    function styleLines(svg) {
      svg.selectAll('path.line')
        .attr({
          fill: 'none',
          'stroke-width': 1.5,
          stroke: 'steelblue',
          'clip-path': 'url(#clip)'
        });
    }

    function styleAxisNodes(axisNodes, strokeWidth) {
      axisNodes.selectAll('.domain')
        .attr({
          fill: 'none',
          'stroke-width': strokeWidth,
          stroke: 'black'
        });
      axisNodes.selectAll('.tick line')
        .attr({
          fill: 'none',
          'stroke-width': 1,
          stroke: 'black'
        });
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a JavaScript file that is an ES6 module. These cannot be loaded directly into the browser, instead you should use the 'bundled' version of the code.

The easiest way to do this is via the top-level d3fc bundle, as documented here: https://d3fc.io/introduction/getting-started.html